# How to embed a Skype chat onto a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, skype

was just wondering how I would add something like this Skype chat box onto my website:

http://www.pwign.com/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Skype web control, you can generate a code snippet to add to your page [here](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol). The link there also has some info on how to customise and style the button and chat pane

According to the page you only need to add a `div` or `span` with the appropriate class to your dom (and specify your skype ID or a skype bot API ID if you wish to link the chat to a bot) and load the skype web control javascript with a script tag or similar

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="YOUR_SKYPE_ID"></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```